# C++ new syntax, pls explain

Tags: c++

What the syntax is called and what does it do? For which c++ standard it is?

```
shared_ptr<int> p{new int{10}};
```

I am confused about the first set of curly brackets `{}`. I suppose, the second set is creating a temporary object of 10 elements?

Comment: It creates 1 int on the heap with a value of 10 I think, then stores it in a shared_ptr

Comment: Read about [uniform initialization syntax](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#uniform-init).

Comment: this would be better expressed as  `auto p = make_shared<int>(10);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What the syntax is called, and what does it do?

This syntax is called *uniform initialization* or *list initialization*. It does many different things [explained here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). In this particular case the construct initializes the shared pointer with a plain pointer to an integer, and sets the newly allocated integer to ten ([demo](http://ideone.com/nencgE)).

The effect is the same as in the code snippet below:

```
int *tmp = new int;
*tmp = 10;
shared_ptr p(tmp);
```

> For which c++ standard it is?

This syntax was introduced in C++11.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, if it is equivalent to `shared_ptr<int> p(new int(10));` , what is this syntax for?

Comment: @Qwertypal This new syntax is more restrictive. For example, if you use a `long long` constant that does not fit in an `int`, like this, `int a(123456789098876543LL);` your variable `a` would get a negative number after truncation ([demo](http://ideone.com/O3kG3h)). If you try the same thing with `{...}`, you would get a compile-time error ([demo](http://ideone.com/71zbpI)).